# Parsing $user_agent on velocity?

Tags: mobile, velocity

I'm trying to dynamically modify (server-side) the output of a page, whether the user is accessing it from a mobile device or not...

I'm using `$user_agent`, which gets me this, if I access the page from my Chrome on my laptop:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1123.4 Safari/536.10
```

I could ask if $user_agent contains MSIE or Mozilla or Windows or whatever (I'd appreciate a clever list for keywords)... but was just wondering if there was a better solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of user agent strings out there for desktop browsers, when we are speaking about mobile devices it's even worse.

I recommend you to use the [WURFL library](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to check whether the actual devices are mobile or not, instead of building your own list.

Comment: Thanks.
I failed to mention: I'm working on a CMS, which I don't administer, my chances of installing/configuring anything on that server are NONE :) So I'll have to confirm with the Admins if they got something like WURFL installed.
Thanks!

Comment: Ohh, that sad. I do not want to be in your place then :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the VelocityTools has a BrowserTool that does all user agent parsing for you.  Definitely the easiest way.